# Ionic3: ion-app ngClass

Tags: angular, ng-class, ionic3

why on ion-app ngClass doesn't works but in ion-content it works?

This is my line of html code

```
<ion-app [ngClass]="'blur-background'"></ion-app>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

you should use

```
<ion-app [ngClass]="{'blur-background':*expression*}"></ion-app>
```

I think you can fix your problem

Comment: <ion-app [ngClass]="{'blur-background':expression}"></ion-app>